# How can I get string before two and above characters [string] ? PHP

Tags: php, string, char

`$string1 = "2-2-2000-2000-";`

How can I get the following result?
`For $output1 -> 2
For $output2 -> 2-2
For $output3 -> 2-2-2000
For $output4 -> 2-2-2000-2000`

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: i had try $s1 = "2-2-2000-2000-2000-";
echo substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, '-', 5));
but it only display untill 2-2-2000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
$array = explode('-', $string1);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    echo 'For $output' . $i . ' -> ' . implode('-', array_slice($array, 0, $i)) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar.. its really help.. i'm just new.. thanks..=)

Comment: if i want output like this $output1 -> 2 For $output2 -> 2 For $output3 -> 2000 For $output4 -> 2000  is it possible?

Comment: That's even easier, those are just the elements of `$array`. Don't you know what `explode()` does?